# post array of numbers to google spreadsheet using android

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to upload array of numbers from android to a google spreadsheet. I have try this solution https://github.com/FoamyGuy/GoogleFormUploadExample/tree/master/src/com/makemyandroidapp/example/googlespreadsheet/post

its work well but it upload single argument as a spreadsheet form entry. what i need is to upload full array say 1000 element at once.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the ready made library [Google Form Uploader](https://github.com/FoamyGuy/GoogleFormUploader) created by one of our developer friend. This would help you in uploading the numbers to the Google Spreadsheet in bulk.

To use this library you need to find your form-id, and your entry id's from the 'Live Form' page source code. Once you have those ids you can upload data to a form like this:

```
GoogleFormUploader uploader = new GoogleFormUploader("1AYvV0gFgB1hBuoRKnMsXy1LyF8-Ce8VAshAtho6Z08s");
uploader.addEntry("1680144410", "Hello Word");
uploader.addEntry("1558298396", "From android app");
uploader.upload();
```

but fill in your own form-id and entry ids.